# Does Ruby regular expression have a not match operator like "!~" in Perl?

Tags: ruby, regex

I just want to know whether ruby regex has a not match operator just like `!~` in perl. I feel it's inconvenient to use `(?!xxx)`or `(?<!xxxx)` because you cannot use regex patterns in the `xxx` part.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Yes: `!~` works just fine – you probably thought it wouldn’t because [it’s missing from the documentation page of `Regexp`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html). Nevertheless, it works:

```
irb(main):001:0> 'x' !~ /x/
=> false
irb(main):002:0> 'x' !~ /y/
=> true
```

Comment: `!~` is documented under [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-21-7E).

Comment: With ruby 2.4, there's also the somewhat nicer syntax `RegExp#match?`, which you can easily negate. According to the [release notes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/), it does even fewer allocations than `!~`

Comment: The object you're calling the method on is a String (not a Regexp), though both can receive Object's `!~` method by virtue of being objects. This method compares two objects via the left operand's class' `=~` method. The example in your answer has a left operand of type string and a right operand/argument of type Regexp so it calls [String's =~ method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#3D~-method); if your left operand were a regexp, it would call [Regexp's =~ method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html#3D~-method).

Comment: How about in a `case` statement's `when` clause?

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK (?!xxx) is supported:

```
2.1.5 :021 > 'abc1234' =~ /^abc/
 => 0
2.1.5 :022 > 'def1234' =~ /^abc/
 => nil
2.1.5 :023 > 'abc1234' =~ /^(?!abc)/
 => nil
2.1.5 :024 > 'def1234' =~ /^(?!abc)/
 => 0
```

Comment: It's a lower-level solution. It's not always easy to convert regexps this way. On the other hand, this solution doesn't depend on top-level programming language ;)

Comment: Fantastic. This easily works in a `case/when` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Back in perl, `'foobar' !~ /bar/` was perfectly perlish to test that the string doesn't contain "bar".

In Ruby, particularly with a modern style guide, I think a more explicit solution is more conventional and easy to understand:

```
input = 'foobar'

do_something unless input.match?(/bar/) 

needs_bar = !input.match?(/bar/)
```

That said, I think it would be spiffy if there was a `.no_match?` method.