# Matching lines w/o the occurence of a keyword with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Here are the lines I want to match with Regex in Ruby:

```
Klima
kjhiasug-Klimaanlage
```

and here is the one I dont want to match:

```
keine Klima
```

For that I need a Regex that does exactly that. I have tried with

```
(?!keine)\s?Klima
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no longer sure which keyword is significant here. What about the cases `keine abc` and `abc Klima`? (Match or no match, for each?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r = /(?<!keine )Klima/

r =~ "Klima"                # => match
r =~ "kjhiasug-Klimaanlage" # => match
r =~ "keine Klima"          # => no match
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like:

```
foo = ["Klima", "kjhiasug-Klimaanlage", "keine Klima"]

foo.select{ |s|
  s[/^Klima|\bKlimaan\B/]
}
```

This is returned when run in IRB:

```
=> ["Klima", "kjhiasug-Klimaanlage"]
```

`\b` and `\B` are word-break markers, used to mark where a word transitions from "word" characters to non-word characters. `\b` marks the word-break boundary, and `\B` is the opposite, i.e., where a word DOESN'T break. The characters `-K` have a word-break between them, so `\b` matches at that point. `nl` has no break because both letters are word-characters in the character-set making up `\w` (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), so `\B` matches.

So, basically `/^Klima|\bKlimaan\B/` says, "find strings starting with Klima, or where Klimaan begins a word but doesn't end it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the inverse matching operator !~

See this question about it:
[Does Ruby regular expression have a not match operator like "!~" in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759091/does-ruby-regular-expression-have-a-not-match-operator-like-in-perl)

```
irb(main):001:0> 'keine Klima' !~ /keine Klima/
=> false
irb(main):002:0> 'kjhiasug-Klimaanlage' !~ /keine Klima/
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 'Klima' !~ /keine Klima/
=> true
```