# Regex match anything except ending string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that matches anything except an exact ending string, in this case, the extension '.exe'.

Examples for a file named:

1. 'foo' (no extension) I want to get 'foo'
2. 'foo.bar' I want to get 'foo.bar'
3. 'foo.exe.bar' I want to get 'foo.exe.bar'
4. 'foo.exe1' I want to get 'foo.exe1'
5. 'foo.bar.exe' I want to get 'foo.bar'
6. 'foo.exe' I want to get 'foo'

So far I created the regex `/.*\.(?!exe$)[^.]*/`
but it doesn't work for cases 1 and 6.

Comment: What's the context? If I were scanning for strings that did not end in `.exe` I would probably just use the ["does not match" operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759091/does-ruby-regular-expression-have-a-not-match-operator-like-in-perl): `s !~ /\.exe$/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^.+?(?=\.exe$|$)
```

- `^` start of string
- `.+?` non [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) match one or more characters...
- `(?=\.exe$|$)` until literal `.exe` occurs at end. If not, match end.

[See demo at Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/tebSTcaRu3)

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: You are a wizard. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a simple replacement work?

```
string.sub(/\.exe\z/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean regex *matching* or *capturing*?

There may be a regex only answer, but it currently eludes me. Based on your test data and what you want to match, doing something like the following would cover both what you want to match and capture:

```
name = 'foo.bar.exe'
match = /(.*).exe$/.match(name)
if match == nil
  # then this filename matches your conditions 
  print name
else
  # otherwise match[1] is the capture - filename without .exe extension
  print match[1]
end
```

Comment: Please use proper Ruby indenting. It helps others understand your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
string pattern = @" (?x)  (.* (?= \.exe$ )) | ((?=.*\.exe).*)";
```

- First match is a positive look-ahead that checks if your string
  ends with `.exe`. The condition is not included in the match.
- Second match is a positive look-ahead with the condition included in the
  match. It only checks if you have something followed by `.exe`.

**(?x) is means that white spaces inside the pattern string are ignored.**
Or don't use (?x) and just delete all white spaces.

It works for all the 6 scenarios provided.

Comment: I can't believe some one down vote this answer, it works.

Comment: Looking at your suggested pattern, it won't work at all. Embedded spaces are significant, and if you look at http://rubular.com/r/wys2Kl2yVL you'll see how it fails. Even if the `x` flag is used, as in http://rubular.com/r/4AEtcOKdAX it continues to fail.

Comment: Common man i used Rgex options (?x) in front of it it makes the pattern more readable. My bad........ But you should know about options that allows white spaces in matching pattern string before you down vote my answer.

Comment: I do know about `x`. It's not new nor is it restricted to Ruby. Your answer didn't mention using `x`, which it should if you're going to use embedded spaces that are insignificant as those would confuse and mislead anyone reading your answer who did not know about them. You added that after my comment. That is why I added the comment, so that you could improve it and avoid further down votes. And even with the flag, your pattern doesn't work as the OP required as it's not correctly handling the first two tests. Also, when referencing user's names be respectful and use the right name.